# iOS receive data from bluetooth and then send information to a database on another server through wi-fi

Tags: ios, database, bluetooth, wifi

Which libraries should I look into for the following tasks?

1. I want to receive a string from another device via Bluetooth (this will require looking at a list of nearby devices and choosing the right one.
2. I then want to send the String to a database via Wi-fi

This is a simple version of what I actually want to do, but I need to know how to do those things first. Also, any design tips would be greatly appreciated (like having multiple screens, which classes to write, etc).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The ordinary iOS Bluetooth APIs are only available if you enter into Apple's "Made for iPod" program. See [MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/)

If your device can use the newer "low energy" Bluetooth LE, you can look in the [corebluetooth framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/)

There is an example of a Bluetooth LE heart rate monitor program [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Introduction/Intro.html).

For WiFi, you can use any of several APIs from Apple and others: Berkeley unix sockets, NSURLConnection, CFNetwork, AsyncSocket, etc.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean receive a string from another iOS device, the statement here about needing to be a part of the "Made For iPod" program is incorrect. This would be required if you mean you are trying to build an accessory for iPhone, iPad, or iPod.

The easiest way to "discover" other iOS devices (running your app) and transfer data between them is `GKSession` from the GameKit Framework. Beam It! is pretty good example code for this.

Once you initialize a `GKSession` just set a `GKSessionDelegate` and set the session's `available` property to `YES`. Check out the four required GKSessionDelegate methods and the Beam It! sample code.

http://arctouch.com/beamit/   //Beam It! code

Comment: +1 for the Beam It code, which uses Apple's Multipeer Connectivity lib. http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to study Apple's [WiTap](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/WiTap/Introduction/Intro.html) sample app.  That will answer your question #1.  For question 2, you can use Apple's coredata.  If you are not familiar with coredata, check out this [site](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/core-data)'s tutorials.

Comment: Doesn't WiTap use the Bonjour service? I need Bluetooth, also I am developing for iOS 5

Comment: Yes, it uses Binjour.  Bonjour is a network discovery service that can be used with Bluetooth or top/ip.  Here is the readme file for WiTap https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/WiTap/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html

Comment: I have played with it in iOS5 for WiFi.  Have not tested the bluetooth myself.

Comment: The Bluetooth part of the WiTap example [is broken in iOS 5](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1753/_index.html) and needs a complete rewrite using a lower-level API to work.